# How to replace all occurrences of a character except the first one in PHP using a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

Given an address stored as a single string with newlines delimiting its components like:

```
1 Street\nCity\nST\n12345
```

The goal would be to replace all newline characters except the first one with spaces in order to present it like:

```
1 Street
City ST 12345
```

I have tried methods like:

```
[$street, $rest] = explode("\n", $input, 2);
$output = "$street\n" . preg_replace('/\n+/', ' ', $rest);
```

I have been trying to achieve the same result using a one liner with a regular expression, but could not figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind pattern to ensure that the matching line is preceded with a newline character. Capture the line but not the trailing newline character and replace it with the same line but with a trailing space:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\n)(.*)\n/', '$1 ', $input)
```

Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/5bd6d

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not solving this with complicated regex but keeping it simple like below. You can split the string with a `\n`, pop out the first split and implode the rest with a space.

```
<?php

$input = explode("\n","1 Street\nCity\nST\n12345");

$input = array_shift($input) . PHP_EOL . implode(" ", $input);

echo $input;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/91001)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex trick here by reversing the string, and then replacing every occurrence of `\n` provided that we can lookahead and find at least one other `\n`:

```php
$input = "1 Street\nCity\nST\n12345";
$output = strrev(preg_replace("/\n(?=.*\n)/", " ", strrev($input)));
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
1 Street
City ST 12345
```

Comment: Very clever! Is it impossible to achieve that with a look-behind without having to reverse the input? (That's what I've been trying to do...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternation pattern that matches either the first two lines or a newline character, capture the first two lines without the trailing newline character, and replace the match with what's captured and a space:

```
preg_replace('/(^.*\n.*)\n|\n/', '$1 ', $input)
```

Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/2fb2f

Answer (score -1):

I leave you another method, the regex is correct as long as the conditions are met, in this way it always works

```
$string=explode("/","1 Street\nCity\nST\n12345");

$string[0]."<br>";
$string[1]." ".$string[2]." ".$string[3]
```